# Java - Highgui.imread return an empty matrix

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to read an image using 
Highgui.imread method in open CV/Java BUT it returns an empty matrix although I make sure that the path of the image is correct.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

            File fileName1 = new File("learning_image.jpeg");
            File fileName2 = new File("test_image.jpeg");

            Mat learningImage = Highgui.imread(fileName1.getAbsolutePath(),Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
            Mat testImage =  Highgui.imread(fileName2.getAbsolutePath(),Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

            System.out.println("learningImage size (cols,rows) "+learningImage.size());
            System.out.println("testImage size (cols,rows) "+testImage.size());
            }
```

The Output is :-

learningImage size (cols,rows) 0x0

testImage size (cols,rows) 0x0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL )."

Since jpeg is supported, I would check for permissions issues, a missing or corrupt file.

See:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: The path of the image has white space                                  "C:\Users\User Name\Documents\Eclipse\JavaTestOpenCV \learning_image.jpeg" ....... May this cause the problem ?

Comment: You had a typo in your filename? I don't see any whitespace in your example here. A typo would explain your result though - since it is a missing file for the reader.

Comment: I'm guessing you are on Windows? No, you should be able to open a file with whitespace. My guess is that you are not referring to the file correctly - why are you passing fileName1.getAbsolutePath() in your function? What is the name of your program directory and your file directory? Put everything in the same directory (if possible) and get rid of getAbsolutePath() and it will probably work.

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer by clicking on the up arrow above the zero next to my answer. Thanks!